# Connect to Gmail using Indy

Tags: delphi, gmail, indy10

I'm trying to log in to Gmail (not the email) through Indy component using Delphi XE5, 
Using this function:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  http : TIdHTTP;
  S, GALX, Email, Pass : String;
  lParam : TStringList;

begin
  try
    lParam := TStringList.Create;
    try
      http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      http.IOHandler := IOHandler;
      http.CookieManager := Cookie;
      http.AllowCookies := true;
      http.HandleRedirects := true;
      http.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0';
      http.Request.Host := 'accounts.google.com';
      http.Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
      http.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

      S := http.Get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin');

      Delete(S, 1, Pos('GALX', S));
      S := Copy(S, 1, Pos('">', S) - 1);
      Delete(S, 1, Pos('value=', S) + length('value='));

      GALX := S;

      lParam.Add('GALX='+GALX);
      lParam.Add('Email='+Email);
      lParam.Add('Passwd='+Pass);

      Memo1.Lines.Add(http.Post('http://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth', lParam));
    finally
      http.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lParam.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Now whenever i try to execute that i get:`HTTP/1.0.405 Method Not Allowed.`
and i only get this error when the email/pass are right, when the email/pass is wrong i get the usual error page, so i'm guessing it's not the `POST` Method that is not allowed.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't assume anything. Is it actually the `Get()` or the `Post()` that is raising the exception?

Answer (score 6):

You are not submitting all of the input fields that `/ServiceLoginAuth` looks for.  If you look at the HTML for `/ServiceLogin`, there are 8 other fields posted to `/ServiceLoginAuth` besides the 3 that you are already sending.  When submitting data from an HTML form, you have to submit everything the HTML form wants to submit, you can't just pick and choose what you want.  Try adding the other fields and see what happens.

You need to provide the `/ServiceLogin` URL in the `TIdHTTP.Request.Referer` property when posting to `/ServiceLoginAuth` so it thinks that the request is coming from `/ServiceLogin`.

You are retrieving `/ServiceLogin` using HTTPS, but you are posting to `/ServiceLoginAuth` using HTTP instead.  You need to use HTTPS.

When the user has multiple Google accounts, `/ServiceLogin` posts to `/AccountChooser`, which then redirects back to `/ServiceLogin` with additional input parameters, so you might need to take that into account as well.

Posting to `/ServiceLoginAuth` redirects to `/CheckCookie`, which then redirects to `/ManageAccount`, so make sure those requests are complete and accurate at each step.

Comment: Well i selected these fields after testing them with Firefox + plugins, if u read what i wrote, i said when the email/pass are wrong i get the "wrong pass" message, but when the infos are right i get 405 error, i guess the page is trying to redirect me to another page when the login is successful which i guess it does not accept the "POST" method, but when i add `?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com...etc` to the URL it doesn't raise that 405 error and i get the successful page.

Comment: You said you get the `405` error when the email/pass are wrong, you did not say anything about getting a `wrong pass` message.

Comment: You can attach a `TIdLog...` component to `TIdHTTP`, or use a debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com), to see exactly what is happening and find out which HTTP request is returning the `405` error.